# Open application on tap push notification

Tags: java, android, cordova, push-notification

Function for creating Push notification is

```
public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String appName = getAppName(this);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);        


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(appName)
            .setTicker(appName)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    String message = extras.getString("message");
    if (message != null) {
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
    }

    String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");
    if (msgcnt != null) {
        mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    tryPlayRingtone();
}
```

When I tap on this, it does nothing.
But it must open my application when tap on push notification is occurred.

*Project build target id Google APIs, based on 4.3 platform, API Level 18.
Androuid support liblary is 13 version. I use Phonegap and [Phonegap PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)*

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with activity in AndroidManifest.xml. I've edited main activity, **NOT** created new ativity, like in docs on github.